# VSCode debug breakpoint - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vscode-debugger

Why does debugger stop at RAPIDClient in /var/runtime/index.js everytime, how can it be made go through that point without having to press F5 everytime. Basically, I want the debugger to stop at only my breakpoints.

```
/**
 * Copyright 2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * This module is the bootstrap entrypoint. It establishes the top-level event
 * listeners and loads the user's code.
 */

"use strict";

const RAPIDClient = require("./RAPIDClient.js");
const Runtime = require("./Runtime.js");
const UserFunction = require("./UserFunction.js");
const Errors = require("./Errors.js");
const BeforeExitListener = require("./BeforeExitListener.js");
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @Rapscallion:  No, did you?